# How do I use an 'int' in an if-then statement in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make it so that a random number will be generated and displayed and the user will input the number and hit the enter button.  If the input text matches the random number generated, it will then do something.  However, when I try to use `if(message=random)` an error appears saying that "An instance of type 'int' can not be assigned to a variable of type 'java.lang.String'.  I do not know what to do or how to fix this.

My code is right here:

```
Public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView number = (TextView)findViewById(R.ID.number);
    number.setText("" + random);

    }

public void enter(View view)
{
    EditText answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    String message = answer.getText().toString();
    if(message=random)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `random` to `String` using `String.valueOf()` method then use `equals()` method

```
if(message.equals(String.valueOf(random))
{

   // Do some stuff..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  As you can probably tell I am new to android development, especially the java part.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two problems here:

---

Q1: How do you compare a `String` and an `int` in Java?

A: You don't.  You either convert the `String` to an `int`, or the `int` to a `String`.  Then you do the comparison with like types.  (Java does not support comparison of primitive types and reference types ... apart from the case where the reference type is a boxed type of the appropriate kind; e.g. comparison of `Integer` and `int` works.)

In this case, it is more convenient to convert the `int` to a String because you don't need to deal with the case where the String is not a valid integer. Thus:

```
if (message.equals(String.valueOf(random)) ...
```

But if you had wanted to test if `random` was (say) *less than* the number represented by `message`, that wouldn't work.  You'd need to do something like this:

```
try {
    if (number < Integer.parseInt(message)) ...

} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // do something ...
}
```

---

Q2: Why did you get that strange compilation error?

```
   "An instance of type 'int' can not be assigned to a variable 
    of type 'java.lang.String'"
```

A: Look at the statement:

```
   if(message=random)
```

You are using `=` where you intended to use `==`.  Your code tries to *assign* the value of `random` to `message`.

Comment: +1 for explaining both options with its usage.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:

1. you are assigning instead of comparing. You should use message == random
2. You are comparing a string to an int. You should convert it using

   int intMessage = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText().toString());

   if(message == random){

system32 answer is probably safer because I am assuming here that your text will be a number.

Comment: Thanks for the background as to why it wasn't working.